# Can I run MAMP to serve files that are hosted on a networked drive?

Tags: git, github, mamp

Currently I run MAMP on my local machine, with website files in the usual htdocs folder which i then push to a remote test-server when ready (usual practice). If I wanted to place my website files on a networked drive during the development phase is this possible?

My main reason for wanting to do this is so that anyone can work on the files from any machine connected to the shared drive in our office and also the shared drive is backed up to an offsite location on a daily basis.

Recently a colleagues Mac died and they lost a lot of local data. I don't want this happening to websites either myself or colleagues are building.

Is this something I can do or is there another way altogether of managing this? I'm aware of Git and Github repositories but I think this is overkill for some of the smaller more basic wordpress sites we are building.

Comment: Yes I've just realised - was googling how to mark as solved and when I came back to remove 'SOLVED' I noticed you'd just done it already. Not used StackOverflow much so good to know the procedure - thanks :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help. There's a _lot_ of information on [meta], start [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) for the most important ones. (BTW, you don't need to say "answering my own Q" or anything: the user card is a different color when it is a self-answer rather than someone else answering.)

Comment: Ha Ha, not exactly doing myself any favours here! Thanks for the heads up again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question - Simply a case of changing the document root in MAMP to the root folder location of your files on the shared drive. Simples.

Comment: What about your databases? That is stored in the MAMP application folder (for Mac). How do your resolve that issue?

Comment: The database can actually sit anywhere that it can be accessed via a Wordpress install. Simply update the database credentials in wp-config.php. MAMP is a server that can run PHP and mySQL but you don't have to store your database in the MAMP folder for it to work.